# MacPorts gcc_select doesn't contain gcc_select

Tags: macports

I want to use different gcc versions easily (to build some whimsy python library). I've installed gcc_select-0.1_6… but it doesn't contain "gcc_select", is it a bug or gcc_select is just a stub now an I should use some different method to select default gcc instead?

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read the description with 'port info gcc_select', you'll see that it says, "gcc_select installs files that allow 'port select' to switch the default version of gcc."